# Differential equation with start condition and maximum capacity

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The house with **1000 people** have got **1 infected** with an unknown virus.
The number of students who are newly infected is proportional to the number of healthy product of current and the current number of infected students. After **2 days** is **5 people** infected. How many of them will be **infected in a week**?

I have calculated this with diferencial equation and i have got 1000 people. Is that OK??

Thanks for answers

My solution:

MAX people: 1000

1. day: 1 infected
2. day: 5 infected

$P (7) = (1000* (\frac{2}{998} e^{10})*e^{5*7}) / ( 1 + (\frac{2}{998} e^{10}) * e^{5*7}) = 999,99 = 1000$

Comment: If you want feedback on your solution, it's probably a good idea to share it with us, not just the answer you obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y$ be the number infected at time $t$, where $y(0)=1$. The model we are asked to use is 
$$y'=ky(1000-y).$$
This is a separable differential equation, which can be rewritten as 
$$\frac{dy}{y(1000-y)}=k\,dt,$$
and then, using partial fractions, as 
$$\frac{1}{1000}\left(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{1000-y}\right)\,dy=k\,dt$$
and then as
$$\left(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{1000-y}\right)\,dy=1000k\,dt.$$
Integrate. We get, since $y$ will stay between $1$ and $1000$,
$$\ln\left(\frac{y}{1000-y}\right)=1000kt+C.\tag{1}$$
Since $y(0)=1$, we get $C=\ln(1/999)=-\ln 999$. 
We have $y(2)=5$. Substituting in our equation we get 
$$\ln(5/995)=2000k -\ln 999,$$
and therefore 
$$k=\frac{1}{2000}\ln(999/199).$$
Finally, take the exponential of both sides of (1). We get
$$\frac{y}{1000-y}=\frac{e^{kt}}{999},$$
where $k$ is known. Set $t=7$. With some manipulation, we get a linear equation for $y(7)$. Solve.

**Remark:** The model should not be taken entirely seriously. One can expect at best a rough fit with reality.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The logistic equations sounds like a good model.

Comment: @LukaToni see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#In_ecology:_modeling_population_growth) - btw, that's a big house.

Comment: :) yes it is @jkn

Comment: I have used that equation but i got 1000 for answer - is that possible?

Comment: It doesn't sound right. Even with an exponential model it takes 8 days to have an infected population of $5^4$ people which is less than 1000.  Furthermore, the logistic model actually never reaches the capacity. 1000 is an asymptote.